# MySQL joining two tables and counting based on conditions

Tags: mysql

table 1 > cats

```
cat1 
cat2
```

table 2 > sites

```
site1 > lang1 > cat2 
site2 > lang2 > cat1
site3 > lang3 > cat1
site4 > lang1 > cat1
site5 > lang2 > cat1
site6 > lang3 > cat2
```

the query should do this :

```
get cats and for every cat go to sites and count sites that belongs to that cat with lang1 , lang2 , lang3
```

I want output to be like :

```
cat1 > lang1 : 41 , lang2 : 11 , lang3 : 24

cat2 > lang1 : 17 , lang2 : 06 , lang3 : 74
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I just found the answer and wanted to share it



SELECT `dir_cats`.*, SUM(CASE WHEN dir_sites.site_lang = "ar" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ar_count, SUM(CASE WHEN dir_sites.site_lang = "en" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS en_count, SUM(CASE WHEN dir_sites.site_lang = "fr" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fr_count FROM (`dir_cats`) LEFT JOIN `dir_sites` ON `site_cat_id` = `cat_id` GROUP BY `dir_sites`.`site_cat_id`

Comment: Share it as an answer to your question not a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer and wanted to share it:

```
SELECT 
  dir_cats.*, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN dir_sites.site_lang = "ar" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ar_count, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN dir_sites.site_lang = "en" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS en_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dir_sites.site_lang = "fr" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fr_count 
FROM (dir_cats) 
  LEFT JOIN dir_sites 
    ON site_cat_id = cat_id 
GROUP BY dir_sites.site_cat_id
```

Comment: You probably want to to `GROUP BY dir_cats.cat_id` instead but I think your idea is fine.

Comment: It works but i have a duplicate results probllem , I posted it here , if you can help please

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52878/joining-two-tables-and-counting-joined-rows

Comment: Awfully amazing...!! This saved me complete rewrite of a module, this exactly what I wanted except that in my case the joins happen on 5 tables (Yeah! that complex schema). Phew!!